# How to turn string into readable by php server way? (ActionScript)

Tags: php, string, actionscript, encoding

So I know that my server on real form submit turns `%CE%EB%E5%E3+%DF%EA%F3%F8%EA%E8%ED` into `Олег Якушкин` . How to peform string transfer from  `Олег Якушкин` into  `%CE%EB%E5%E3+%DF%EA%F3%F8%EA%E8%ED` using ActionScript? (Its ok if a space character as %20, not + , PHP should handle that fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can encode it using ActionScript's escape() method.

Comment: ActionScript's escape does not turn Олег Якушкин into %CE%EB%E5%E3+%DF%EA%F3%F8%EA%E8%ED .